# Bloginfo Description not showing

Tags: wordpress, title

Hi I have looked everywhere for help topics on this and not had any luck, I currently run a fan based website. I'm using wordpress and designed my own theme, when I view the page source I know that my description in the < title > tag is not showing. In the dashboard settings I have the tagline filled in, so I'm not sure why it's not showing in the code. Below is what I have coded myself in the  tag area:

```
<title><?php bloginfo('name'); ?> <?php wp_title('&laquo;', true, 'right'); ?> | <?php bloginfo('description'); ?></title>
```

I would appreciate any help on this, as I've been stuck on this for weeks now lol

Antony

Answer (score 2):

I managed to solve the problem I had a plugin installed called "All in One SEO Pack", that seemed to be overriding the Bloginfo description. Once the plugin was deactivated, the description came back.